# Can't automatically log in to chat.se, post to /user/login returns 404

Tags: bug, chat, login

When I tried to access chat.se, I got the message that I need to log in to chat.

The automatic login feature hangs forever, inspecting the console reveals that the POST call to /user/login returns a 404 Not Found error.

Logging in "via stackexchange.com" seemed to have worked.